# fancybox history length iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

how do you get the history length of a fancybox iframe?

i've tried window.history.length and self.history.length
which is obviously not what i want.

i'm not sure if the following can be used since this is a fancybox iframe:

```
document.getElementById('#iframe-name').contentWindow.history.length
```

Comment: I am afraid is going to be always `1` in most browsers and `0` in IE unless you click a link inside the iframe

Comment: @JFK  yep, that's what i encounter.  thanks for the response.